# writing Bytes into a .Bin file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, fstream, ofstream, writetofile

I have a vector in C++ that I want to write it to a .bin file.
this vector's type is `byte`, and the number of bytes could be huge, maybe millions.
I am doing it like this:

```
if (depthQueue.empty())
    return;

FILE* pFiledep;

pFiledep = fopen("depth.bin", "wb");

if (pFiledep == NULL)
    return;

byte* depthbuff = (byte*) malloc(depthQueue.size() * 320 * 240 * sizeof(byte));

if(depthbuff)
{
  for(int m = 0; m < depthQueue.size(); m++)
  {
    byte b = depthQueue[m];
    depthbuff[m] = b;
  }

  fwrite(depthbuff, sizeof(byte),
        depthQueue.size() * 320 * 240 * sizeof(byte), pFiledep);
  fclose(pFiledep);
  free(depthbuff);
}
```

`depthQueue` is my vector which contains bytes and lets say its size is 100,000.
Sometimes I don't get this error, but the bin file is empty.
Sometime I get heap error.
Somtimes when I debug this, it seems that malloc doesn't allocate the space.
Is the problem is with space?

Or is chunk of sequential memory is so long and it can't write in bin?

Comment: Why do you copy the vector into a buffer at all? What type is `depthQueue`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need hardly any of that.  `vector` contents are guaranteed to be contiguous in memory, so you can just write from it directly:

```
fwrite(&depthQueue[0], sizeof (Byte), depthQueue.size(), pFiledep);
```

Note a possible bug in your code: if the vector is indeed `vector<Byte>`, then you **should not** be multiplying its size by 320*240.

**EDIT:** More fixes to the `fwrite()` call: The 2nd parameter already contains the `sizeof (Byte)` factor, so don't do that multiplication again in the 3rd parameter either (even though `sizeof (Byte)` is probably 1 so it doesn't matter).

Comment: Concurrency::concurrent_vector<byte> depthQueue;

Comment: @user667222: I don't know what a `Concurrency::concurrent_vector` is -- you need to check its docs to see whether it provides the same contiguity guarantee.  Also be consisten: is it `byte` or `Byte`?

Comment: @user667222: Given that you seem to be dealing with concurrency, if any other thread or process can write to the vector, you'll probably need to lock it before the `fwrite()` call and unlock it afterwards.

Comment: for now there is no concurrency issues, think of it as normal vector<>

Comment: @user667222: You can't just "think of it as normal vector" -- whether my code works depends on whether the type guarantees that all elements will be laid out contiguously in memory.  It probably does, but *you need to check that*.

Comment: and the type is BYTE not byte or Byte

Comment: i did the modification you said, there is no error BUT the created bin file is empty, could it be because of the size? writing of millions of BYTE?

Comment: @user667222: Writing millions of bytes at a time should not be a problem.  The one problem I can remember having was when trying to write blocks >64Kb to a network drive on Windows a few years ago, but that seems unlikely.  Is the disk full?  Are you calling `fclose()`? Try changing the type to `std::vector` and seeing if that works.

Comment: thanks for your help, here is the issues: actually i am writing the depth values from kinect to a bin file so i have a thread which reads depth values for me, so to prevent invalid allocations for read/write to that depth i am using Concurrency::concurrent_vector<BYTE> instead of std::vector<BYTE> that you just said. i changed to std::vector and i saw values in Bin file but now as i said i got heap errors. when i am using concurrency the values are in already in depthQueue and when fwrite there is no error but bin file come up empty !! appreciate helps (i am doing fclose as you see in the code

Comment: @user667222: My guess is that the concurrent vector type doesn't support directly accessing the underlying memory -- as I said before, *check its documentation*.

Comment: ok thanks, it seems that the problem was because of the .bin file. when i wrote large amount of data the file is empty but when i write a small chunk it is ok, before i tried to store all frames depth at once in a file now for each frame i am creating an individual bin file and it is ok! i dont know the limitations of the bin file, maybe it has a maximum capacity or line length ..

Comment: @user667222: You *know* it's not the bin file, because it works when you use `std::vector`! The problem is either the limitations of the `concurrent_vector` type (READ ITS DOCS) or with your concurrency logic.